# Unable to host flask in firebase using cloud run

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-run

[Repeatedly this error comes in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upJYk.jpg)

```
gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/atlas-mania-ybtcga/atlas-mania-ybtcga
```

I am trying to host my flask api using firebase cloud run, [Following this tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579)  but am get stuck after applying above mentioned command as it is unable to find my project even if i have already selected my project using `gcloud init`.

Comment: Are you using an old version of `gcloud`? Run `gcloud components update` to check.

Comment: Did you build your container? Is it stored at the specified location?

Comment: How to know if it is stored at a specified location

Comment: Got this link as source : gs://atlas-mania-ybtcga_cloudbuild/source/1620286214.33-a865af8ce76f40bbac4a75e5f238f2cc.tgz

Comment: Pardon me, but can you confirm that the "--image" tag you're using is the same as the "--tag" tag you used in the previous step (step 4, where it indicates `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project-id>/flask-fire` as the command to follow)?

Comment: yes it is the same tag

Comment: I assume you've already tried using the regular `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/atlas-mania-ybtcga/atlas-mania-ybtcga`, so to answer the question you were making to guillaume, simply access the image link you've provided (`grc.io/atlas-mania-ybtcga/atlas-mania-ybtcga`). PS we do not get notified of comments or answers made to this post unless you mention us, to do so you use the `@` sign, followed by the user's handle, or part of it, for example @guillaume will likely call mr. blaquiere (sorry about this mr blaquiere, btw)

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention... if the image is in a different region (asia or europe) you might need to ask the appropriate prefix see [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#add-registry) for a quick list on the regions.

Comment: Sir @JohnHanley you were correct ' gcloud components update ' wasn't working I uninstalled and installed again to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption of @JohnHanley was correct, you use a old version of gcloud. The gcloud CLI is may be up to date, but not the beta one.

Your GCLOUD cli tries to access to the v1alpha1 API of Cloud Run which no longer exists.

Remove the beta key word in your command or update the beta GCLOUD component.